# matplotlib, show only positive numbers starting from 0 on both sides on the X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a plot with matplotlib with cylindrical symmetry. it means on both sides on X-axes positive (absolute values) numbers similar to this plot.

Plot that I get, but numbers on the left side of X-axes negative (that need to be positive too):
[image: plot that I get, but numbers on the left side of X-axes negative]

Comment: Can you describe more exactly what you mean by *getting positive numbers on both sides of the X-axes*? Do you want to show the absolute values? Or the values modulo some constant? Or ...?  Can you also add minimal reproducible example code, including some test data?

Comment: You could try something like `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{abs(x):.0f}')`

Comment: If you have cylindrical symmetry, do you really need the negative numbers at all?

Comment: I don't need negative values, I need absolute values on the X-axes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the format of the [matplotlib.xaxis.Tick object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axis_api.html#tick-objects) label. In matplotlib there are usually a lot of ways to do things and this is no exception.

Matplotlib figures out where the ticks should be with a [tick locator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html). Then a [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) defines what kind of text should be in those tick labels. The default formatter for numerical data is ScalarFormatter.

An alternative locator or formatter is easy to define with the matplotlib ticker library. Once you get the hang of this, its actually quite easy. Here is an example that shows how to fix your problem.

[image: Link to plot image (I can't put images in my posts)]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import ticker

# define fig and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2, figsize=(17.5,6))    
axes = axes.flatten()   # make axes a 1D array

x = np.linspace(-20,20) # make some x values between -20 and 20
y = np.sin(x/4)         # make some y values that are sin(x/4)

for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.5) # plot x and y values

#Make a function that makes negative values positive (lots of ways to do this)
def neg_to_pos(n, position):
    n = int(n)
    if n < 0:
        return str(n * -1)
    else:
        return str(n)

#access the bottom plot object xaxis object and set the
#major tick formatter to be a FunctionFormatter that uses
#the neg_to_pos function
xaxis_formatter = axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(neg_to_pos))

#add titles, x labels, and y labels
title_ax0 = axes[0].set_title('Default formatter', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
title_ax1 = axes[1].set_title('FuncFormatter', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
xlabels = [ax.set_xlabel('x_values') for ax in axes]
ylabels = [ax.set_ylabel('y_values') for ax in axes]
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5) #fix the vertical spacing between the plots
```

The links I placed above for locators and formatters are bookmarked for me and I refer to them often when working on axis tick problems.

Comment: Formatter should return a string. `neg_to_pos` can be just `lambda x, pos: str(abs(x))`

Comment: it's work, thanks, but I think its "from matplotlib import ticker", by me its work. I have python 3